# Creating a ContextProvider for a Form Component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-context

I have created some context for a form component that I have created.  Right now, I have created a Provider for that context at the root of my app.  But I am wondering if this is the best way to do things.

There are many pages that do not have forms on them.  Why should I provide uneeded code on those pages?  Or is it not really that big a deal?

If it's better NOT to do it, then any ideas on how I can add the provider ONLY on those pages that use the form component?

Comment: you should take a look at [formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a HOC with that Provider, and use that only in the components you want.

```
const withForm = Component => {    
    return (
        <Provider>
            <Component />
        <Provider>        
    )
}

// other file 
export const MyComponentWithForm = withForm(MyComponent)
```

This example is very simplified, but it's only so you can understand how it should work (there is alot of missing pieces in this HOC).

Also notice that you can also do this for `Consumer` **if you are using class components**.